# How do I open a .gpg file from the command line?

Tags: term, gpg, revert-buffer

I have a file located in the directory `~/myfiles/list.txt.gpg`.

In the terminal, I type `emacs ~/myfiles/list.txt.gpg` and I get something that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJx4A.png),
which I'm guessing is the still encrypted form of the file.

In order to get it to display properly, I have to `M-x revert-buffer`, then it will prompt me for the password and load it the file properly.

My question is: How can I get Emacs to recognize it is encrypted and prompt me for the password immediately instead of having to go through the trouble of pressing `M-x` and selecting `revert-buffer`?

Comment: Did you load epa as documented in the wiki? https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EasyPG .  Specifically:- (require 'epa-file)
    (epa-file-enable)

Comment: I added this to my config but I get the same behavior, any other suggestions?

Comment: DId you restart your emacs after adding that to your config? If it still misbehaves, add just those two lines in a file (say `/tmp/epa-config.el`) and invoke emacs like this: `emacs -Q -l /tmp/epa-config.el ~/myfiles/list.txt.gpg`. This should work (in which case, you should figure out what in your config is creating the problem).

Comment: Indeed that works! I guess that means something is wrong with my config.

Comment: Maybe you didnt evaluate them? Else follow NickD's advice. I shall make my comment an answer and please mark it as the answer. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Evaluating-Emacs-Lisp-code.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you load epa as documented in the wiki?

[emacswiki.org/emacs/EasyPG](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EasyPG) . Specifically:-

```
(require 'epa-file)
(epa-file-enable)
```

After that evaluate the code or restart. Refer to [the emacs documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Evaluating-Emacs-Lisp-code.html)
for details on how to evaluate the code "in buffer".